# Registry entry for iFilter does not stay after system reboot

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, sharepoint-search, wss-3.0-sp2

we followed the article at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927675/en-us to implement the pdf filter for wss 3.0.
But the registry entry mentioned on step 2 (adding a new entry under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0\Search\Applications\GUID\Gather\Search\Extensions\ExtensionList**) is lost if we reboot the system.

Does anyone have any idea why that might be happening?
We installed the adobe reader 10 and tried to configure the pdf filter for wss 3.0

Comment: Wss 3.0 is running on windows server 2008R2 - 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. After changing the registry you have to stop and restart the share point search service. No idea how they are related tho!

Following are the commands:
net stop spsearch
net start spsearch